# Where does apt-get install libqt4?

Tags: apt, qt, qt-creator

I've been searching for literally hours and I cannot figure out where for the life of me libqt4 is installed by apt-get.

I installed:

```
libqt4-dev
libqt4-core
libqt4-gui
libqt4-xml
libqt4-opengl
```

Next, I installed QtCreator 2.5.2 with the binary install file downloaded from qt-project.org because the QtCreator available in the Ubuntu repos is only 2.4.

QtCreator has to be able to find qt libraries and qmake on my system, but I can't even find them.  Does anyone know where the $*(^#$(&^# apt-get installs them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find out where files are installed with dpkg:

`dpkg --listfiles libqt4-dev`

Comment: This is the sort of all purpose solution I was looking for.  Googling for a way to show paths to packages installed with apt-get didn't show this...not even on the apt-get faq!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

The library files are usually in `/usr/include/qt4`. The qmake is in `/usr/bin/qmake-qt4` (or `/usr/bin/qt4-qmake`, I forget). You may have to symbolic link `/usr/bin/qmake` to either of these.

Perhaps your application expected the files to be in `/usr/local/include...` and `/usr/local/bin...` like some other distrubutions?

Comment: The include files were indeed in /usr/include, but the libraries were actually installed in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.

Answer (score 2):

So, after following roadmr's advice, I was able to find out that the libraries were installed in:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

However, to set up QtCreator, one need only find the location of the qmake executable, which I believe Bodie was hinting at.  It turned out that qmake (or qmake-qt4) was located in :

```
/usr/bin
```

Thanks to both for the guidace!