# Boost version chaos, how to remove all traces from source build?

Tags: package-management, compiling, c++, libraries, cmake

**My problem is:**

I installed boost from source, everything works fine. CMake finds the library.
Then I realized that I need bjam, installed it with apt-get for Ubuntu.
This creates a version mismatch. I tried to uninstall the manually installed boost and installed a system package. Big chaos.
Cmake can no longer find Boost, I don't understand how to configure it to fix this problem.

**Question:**

- How do I explicitly tell Cmake to look for the system package boost ?
- Alternative: How do I remove all traces from that manual installation (see below, last paragraph)

**Details:**

I followed this tutorial to install boost from source:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#test-your-program

I followed the easy build instructions : downloaded and extracted the latest source, then ran bootstrap without additional arguments (install dir = default = usr/local) and used `sudo b2 install`

The sample program (with the regex) ran without problems.
Then I hooked up CMake and tested if FindBoost worked.
This question shows how to do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake

Worked like a charm, I didn't have to configure the lib and include paths, just used the code from the accepted answer.

Unfortunately I need Boost.Python which has an additional dependency: `bjam`.
While looking for installation instructions for `bjam`, I realized that I could just install the Ubuntu package `libboost1.58-tools-dev`, it contains `bjam` .
I installed this package and ran the quickstart test example from the downloaded boost source.
The test complained that there was a version mismatch. That's right, I installed 1.61 (latest version) from source. But my system package is 1.58 (that's the `bjam` version).

Now I tried to delete boost. Apparently you have to do that manually by removing everything boost related from /usr/local. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=892951
Then I installed the system package `libboost1.58-dev` as counterpart to `libboost1.58-tools-dev`.
This creates a new problem: Cmake can no longer find boost. It complains that the expected version is 1.5, but the given version is 0.0.0

This question (How to link C++ program with Boost using CMake) describes how to configure an alternative path for boost libraries (not the accepted answer). I tried to do the same.

I used this [Where does apt-get install libqt4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178312/where-does-apt-get-install-libqt4) to find where apt-get put my system boost package.
But it only tells me that some files are in usr/include.
I can't find the lib files.

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} /usr/include/boost")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "/.../boost/lib")  <---- this path needs to be set
```

**Also interesting:**

I installed Eigen3 as a system package with apt-get, and cmake can find it without any additional configuration.

Therefore I think that there are still traces of that first installation from source. I believe, if I had just installed the Ubuntu boost package from the beginning, I wouldn't have this problem.
Is that possible ?

Comment: The tutorial you linked provides a number of options - can you at least summarize the *actual* steps you took to install from source? For example did you just extract the archive somewhere (if so, where?), or use the bootstrap (if so, with what prefix?)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Sure, I'll edit the question right away.

Comment: So... to summarize your current state: you have installed `libboost1.58-tools-dev` from the repository, and then you attempt to build some sample from the boost 1.61 source, `cmake` can't find boost, is that correct? If so, did you start over with a clean directory for the sample code - `cmake` caches variables and that seems to be the only reliable way to ensure it is not using the cached versions.

Comment: Yes, my sample is a clean directory.

Comment: I copied the sample code out of the boost directory to a clean folder

Comment: And deleted all temp cmake files between my build attemps